# How to have unselected dgv?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I use a method that changes color of some rows but a row remains selected.
How can I unselect all dgv? This code doesn't work.

```
dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex = -1;
```

I get an error `"dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex is readonly"`

Comment: @Habib what do you mean by targeting?

Comment: @Habib this works perfect for me, sorry for the stupid question. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you are using Winforms,

Comment: You should [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=if+(!JQuery)+throw+%7B+new+exception(%22JQuery+is+not+defined.%22)%3B+%7D&oq=if+(!JQuery)+throw+%7B+new+exception(%22JQuery+is+not+defined.%22)%3B+%7D&aqs=chrome..69i57.1403j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+datagridview+clear+selection) it before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataGridView.ClearSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection(v=vs.110).aspx) method. like:

```
dgv.ClearSelection();
```

This will remove the row selection but you will still get the indication for current row.

[image]

To remove that use `DataGridView.CurrentCell` like:

```
dgv.CurrentCell = null;
```

This will give you:

[image]